# How to update Google Cloud Platform Legacy GAE and GCF Metadata Server endpoints

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I am using firebase cloud functions with Node to send push notifications triggered by realtime database events.

I got this email from Google telling me to update my requests to use the v1 endpoint. The email states:

*Our records show that you own projects with App Engine applications or Cloud Functions that are still calling the pre-GA v0.1 and v1beta1 endpoints of the App Engine and Cloud Functions metadata server.*

*Identify the projects, apps and functions which are making these requests.
Attached to this message you will find the list of projects, applications and functions that you own that have made requests to the v0.1 and v1beta1 metadata server endpoints between Sept 26, 2019 and Nov 1, 2019.*
**Comment: I know what project it is.**

*Upgrade your Google client libraries to the latest versions. See supported library versions for the list of Google SDKs that require an update.*
**Comment: this I don't understand. Do I need to do this?**

*If you are making direct requests to the legacy Metadata Server endpoints:
To ensure minimal interruption to your instances, please update your requests to the v1 endpoint before April 30, 2020.*
**Comment: I don't know if I'm making direct requests**

*How to upgrade from v1beta1 request to v1 requests:
If you are making direct requests to the v1beta1 URI, please follow the following steps to upgrade to the v1 URI:
Change the request URI to use v1 instead of v1beta1
Add this header to your request: “Metadata-Flavor: Google”
For example, if you’re currently making this request:
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1beta1/instance/id"
Upgrade to v1 as follows:
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/id” -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
How to upgrade from v0.1 requests to v1 requests:
If you are making direct requests to the v0.1 URI, please follow the following steps to upgrade to the v1 URI:
Change the request URI to use v1 instead of v0.1
Add this header to your request: “Metadata-Flavor: Google”
Use these instructions to map the v0.1 properties to the v1 properties
For example, if you’re currently making this request:
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/0.1/meta-data/instance-id"
Upgrade to v1 as follows:
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/id” -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
Redeploy your application
The steps above will require another application deployment to take effect.*

I searched the Google Cloud support webb (as suggested in the email) and here on SO. But I don’t understand how to do this.

Please bare in mind I’m a complete novice. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**
Apparently this function has made requests to the v0.1 and v1beta1 metadata server endpoints:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendErrorInputWasSentPush = functions.database.ref('/errorInputs/{barcode}/{date}').onWrite((change, context) => {

const barcode = context.params.barcode
const dataAfter = change.after.val()
const input = dataAfter.input
const pushIDs = [
    "", 
    ""]

console.log(`Error input submitted.`)

const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: '',
        body: '',
        sound: "default"
    }
};

const options = {
    priority: "high",
    timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
};

return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(pushIDs, payload, options);
```

});

Firebase versions:

```
"firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.2.0"
```

Comment: Can you share this email and your code to understand what is the Google request?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I added the main contents of the email. As far as my code is concerned. What do you need to see? My Node.js code?

Comment: What is the admin object? How it is created? What are your dependencies version?

Comment: Added some more code. Sorry for not being clearer, and thank you for your patience!

Comment: No problem. And your version of firebase in your package.json ?

Comment: Updated my answer with Firebase versions

Comment: Thanks, with all the details, I updated my answer.

Comment: I also received the email from Google regarding the same. Some functions were using the old version of firebase-admin. But Now I redeployed all of the functions with the latest `firebase-admin (8.9.0)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you never perform any query to `http://metadata.google.internal/...` URL from your code or script, that changes nothing!

If you use this URL, paste your code, we could help you.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to your details, I found the problem in the file [`src/auth/credential.ts`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/src/auth/credential.ts) of [firebase-admin-node github project](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node). Up to the version 8.1.0 the value of the line 32 is:

```
const GOOGLE_METADATA_SERVICE_PATH = '/computeMetadata/v1beta1/instance/service-accounts/default/token';
```

Use the version `8.2.0` or above to solve this

Comment: Wow! Well done. Too bad I don’t follow; where do you find this file and what dependency should I upgrade to 8.2.0?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/src/auth/credential.ts), line 32. You can play with `branch` drop down list, select TAG for viewing the version related to each version.

Comment: So this is not even about `firebase-functions` node module but the `firebase-admin`?